# Para Generation and Drawing Conclusion from X give Articles

Tags: machine-learning

I was wondering any examples of the following;

- para generation: For eg, given X similar paragraphs,  are you able to build a model to learn the style and generate a new para that is a paraphrase of the X paras. Similar in meaning but diff wording.
- drawing conclusions from X given articles. He has a list of conclusions, check the X articles can provide evidence to the conclusions. Eg, given conclusion “city is not safe”, look for evidence such as “murders” and “thefts”.

Glady Appreciate,
Betty

Comment: Welcome to AI!  Could you please clarify your terms?  When you say "para" , are you meaning "paragraph" or "paraphrase" or something else entirely?  I'm assuming the "diff" is intended, to connote line-oriented comparison function.  Apologies if my questions stem from ignorance of terms of art being utilized.)

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrase generation would be made by an [abstractive text summarization tool](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-in-python-extractive-vs-abstractive-techniques-revisited/#abstractive_text) like Tensorflow as described in [Google's blog](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/text-summarization-with-tensorflow.html?m=1).

Abstractive tool summarizes the text but also it adds extra words to make text more human like.

About the second problem scenario I would say the answer depends quite much what you mean by the conclusions and how you think the conclusions would be made. I strongly believe this falls in the category of [artificial general intelligence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence), which is emerging area of AI, supported by association [AGI](http://www.agi-society.org), where the focus is on strong artificial intelligence and more human like features of AI.

Judging about conclusions at least needs a vast knowledge base of the semantics of different words and pieces of text in general combined to possible conclusions and their legitimate implications.